# Cogs not working in discord.py load extension

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[image]

[image]

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class CommandEvents(commands.cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
            await ctx.send("**Invalid command. Try using** `help` **to figure out commands!**")
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            await ctx.send('**Please pass in all requirements.**')
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
            await ctx.send("**You dont have all the requirements or permissions for using this command :angry:**")
    @commands.command(name="ping")
    async def ping(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        await ctx.send(f"Pong! {round(self.bot.latency * 1000)}ms")
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(CommandEvents(bot))
```

thats my cog. When im trying to setup the Bot this will happen. so idk i searched so much how i can use cogs but idk. Im new to cogs this is my first time using them.

my Main Pogramm

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
token = ""
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '-')

bot.load_extension("CommandEvents")
bot.run(token)
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: u need to specify path of the file

Answer (score 0):

Line 4 of your cog file: You typed `commands.cog`. Since Python is case sensitive, you have to type `commands.Cog` with the C in uppercase.
Also:

You have to put in the full path of the cog. You've just typed "CommandEvents" but it should be "cogs.CommandEvents".

Comment: bruhhh i got it i had to ```bot.load_extension("cog.CommandEvents")``` but ty for ur help